# Resolving a class property type with dot notation

Tags: java, apache-commons-beanutils

I need to resolve a Java class's property type with support for dot notation. Is there any library that can do this? The signature of the method I am looking for will look something like this:

```
getPropertyType(Person.class, "job.phone.areaCode");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using reflection. The code below, basically, uses the method 'getDeclaredField' from reflection api to retrieve the type of the desired field. It works navigating trough the dots of the dot notation field name.

```
public static Class<?> getPropertyType(Class<?> clazz, String fieldName) {
    final String[] fieldNames = fieldName.split("\\.", -1);
    //if using dot notation to navigate for classes
    if (fieldNames.length > 1) {
        final String firstProperty = fieldNames[0];
        final String otherProperties =
            StringUtils.join(fieldNames, '.', 1, fieldNames.length);
        final Class<?> firstPropertyType = getPropertyType(clazz, firstProperty);
        return getPropertyType(firstPropertyType, otherProperties);
    }

    try {
        return clazz.getDeclaredField(fieldName).getType();
    } catch (final NoSuchFieldException e) {
        if (!clazz.equals(Object.class)) {
            return getPropertyType(clazz.getSuperclass(), fieldName);
        }
        throw new IllegalStateException(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Although this code may be help to solve the problem,
providing additional context regarding _why_ and/or _how_ it
answers the question would significantly improve its
long-term value.  Please [edit] your answer to add some
explanation.

Comment: A better approach would be to use the getter method of the class instead of directly accessing the field.